# Ramification filtration for automorphism group of Artin-Schreier curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am studying the curve over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_3 = K$ defined by the equation $y^3 - y = x^4$. The automorphism group I am looking at is the one generated by elements $\sigma$ and $\tau$ where

$\sigma^*(x) = x$, $\sigma^*(y) = y+1$

$\tau^*(x) = \zeta x$, $\tau^*(y) = \zeta^4 y$.

Here, $\zeta$ is a primitive 8-th root of unity and so we can also write $\tau^*(y) = -y$. One can easily check that $\tau \sigma = \sigma^2 \tau$, and so $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} / 3\mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z} / 8\mathbb{Z}$.

I now want to study the ramification over the point $\infty$, and in particular the lower ramification filtration. I then change affine charts and localize around 0 so that we end up looking at an extension of power series rings. The issue I run into is that $\tau^2$ acts as the identity (in both affine charts) on y, so the artin character is not defined for $\tau^2$.

My question is this: Does it not make sense to look at the ramification filtration for this cover?

Comment: I'm only familiar with the language of function fields, so I may not be fully conversant with everything. Anyway, don't you have here a simple tower of function field extensions $K(x^8)\subset K(x)\subset K(x,y)$ with $K(x)/K(x^8)$ being cyclic of degree 8 and $K(x,y)/K(x)$ an Artin-Schreier extension of degree 3. Your group, call it $G$, is the Galois group $G=Gal(K(x,y)/K(x^8))$, and the point at $\infty$ corresponds to $x^8=\infty$, right?

Comment: Anyway, shouldn't the subgroup $\langle \tau\rangle$ be at the top ramification group, because its order is coprime to $3$ - just like 8-fold branching at the North/South poles of a Riemann sphere. The Artin-Schreier step is then all wild ramification. Sorry, it's too late for me to start and calculate how high ramification groups occur.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful response! I'm so used to the Galois extension being over $K(x)$ that I completely missed this being a tower of function fields. This aside, I agree with everything you have said. I will try to compute the higher ramification groups myself and hopefully I will be able to answer this question soon!

Answer (score 0):

As Jyrki Lahtonen pointed out, we are considering a tower of fields given by $K(x^8) \subset K(x) \subset K(x,y)$. When we localize around $\infty$ we end up with a totally ramified extension $K((\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})) / K((\tilde{x}^8))$. I use the ~ to denote we've changed affine open sets, and the fact this is totally ramified follows $K$ being algebraically closed.

As $K(\tilde{x}) / K(\tilde{x^8})$ is Galois, we may consider the group $G/<\sigma> = G/H$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$. Using the notation of Serre, we have that

$i_{G/H}(\tau) = \frac{1}{e'}\sum_{s->\sigma} i_G(s)$ where $e' = e_{K(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})/K(\tilde{x})} = 3$. Just by considering the cardinalities of the groups, we have that $|\{ s\in G: s-> \tau\}|=3$.

Finally, for any $\tau \in G/H$, we have that $\tau(\tilde{x}) = x/a$ where $a\in K$ satisfies $a^8 = 1$. Thus $i_{G/H}(\tau^k) = 1$ for all $k \neq 8$.

It follows that $i_G(s) = 1$ for all $s\neq 1$. Certainly each $s\in G$ satisfies $i_G(s) \geq 1$ by the fact this is totally ramified, but it is at most one as $i_{G/H}(\tau) = 1 = \frac{1}{e'}\sum_{s->\sigma} i_G(s) = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{s->\sigma} i_G(s)$.

Thus the lower ramification filtration is $G = G_0 \supset \{1\}$.